# how to call magento2 cli commands from controller?

Tags: magento2, command-line

i created some custom command.in one scenario i need to execute this command in the background in controller file.

i'm trying to use following syntax.but its not working.

```
exec('php bin/magento  kensium:fetchrecord customer ' > /dev/null & 1 & echo $!', $out);
```

Comment: If somebody wants to run one CLI command inside another here's the [relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44532524/1443197). I haven't tried it with cotrollers though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should not call command lines from controller.
as I see, this is a custom command.
You can implement your logic in a model.
Then you can call that model from the cli and from controller, but don't call `exec` from a controller.
But if you insist, it seams to me you are doing it right. Just check your server settings to see if you are allowed to call `exec`.

Comment: my logic will take more time.so i should allow to customer do  other actions from admin.so that he can close that popup(but in the background the process will run)

Comment: then you should put your logic into a model, like Marius said. Then implement a cronjob that calls the model and schedule / trigger it from your controller