# Magento 2: How to call a command from a Controller?

Tags: magento2, controllers, backend, command

I have created a command and now I need to call it from a controller. How to do it?

**This is the command:**

```
class CleanVarnish extends Command
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('varnish:clean')
            ->setDescription('Clean Varnish command line');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $output->writeln('sudo /usr/bin/varnishadm "ban req.url ~ "/" "');
    }
}
```

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/100762/how-to-call-magento2-cli-commands-from-controller

Comment: @EvgeniyKapelko he says not to call the exec(), I already have created my command and now I need to call it from the controller

Comment: You need to call your custom command file in controller then you can call execute method by that files object. May I know why you want to call command in your controller?  actually, you can copy code from that command file amd put that in your controller.

Comment: @kunj Is to run it from the backend, could you give me an example?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36748588/console-symfony-call-command-from-controller